# Estimating the asymptotic distribution of a quasi maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: time-series, estimation, garch, quasi-maximum-likelihood

We consider the following GARCH(1, 1) model:

$y_t = h_t \epsilon_t$ where $(\epsilon_t)_{t \in \{1, \dots, n\}}$ are i.i.d. random variables with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

$h_t = \omega + \alpha \epsilon_{t-1}^2 + \beta h_{t-1}^2$

A standard way of estimating the parameters of such a model is to use the quasi maximum likelihood method, i.e. maximising the log-likelihood of the model under the assumption that the $(\epsilon_t)_{t \in \{1, \dots, n\}}$ are gaussian, that is:

$\displaystyle\mathscr{l}(\omega, \alpha, \beta, y_1, \dots, y_n) = -\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=1}^n\left(\log(h_t) + \frac{y_t^2}{h_t}\right)$

The estimator is shown to have good properties even if this assumption does no hold. The asymptotic distribution of that estimator is:

$\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}\left(0, A(\theta_0)^{-1} B(\theta_0) A(\theta_0)^{-1}\right)$

where $\hat{\theta}_n$ is the vector of estimated parameters, $\theta_0$ the true vector of parameters, $B(\theta_0)$ the outer product of the gradient and $A(\theta_0)$ the Hessian matrix, both evaluated at the true value of the parameters.

We can get a good approximation of the Hessian asymptotically by replacing the true value of the parameter by its estimate. But when it comes to the gradient, $B(\hat{\theta}_n)$ is by definition equal to zero since $\hat{\theta}_n$ maximises $\mathscr{l}$. So it cannot be a good approximation of $B(\theta_0)$.

That leads me to my question: how do you estimate the covariance matrix of the asymptotic distribution of the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** What is set equal to zero is the gradient of the log-likelihood *of the whole sample*, namely

$$\frac {\partial}{\partial \theta}\displaystyle\mathscr{l}(\theta, y_1, \dots, y_n) = \frac {\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=1}^n\left(\log(h_t) + \frac{y_t^2}{h_t}\right)\right) = 0$$

This gives us a sum of derivatives (each derivative for each observation).

$$\frac {\partial}{\partial \theta}\displaystyle\mathscr{l}(\theta, y_1, \dots, y_n) = \frac {\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(h_1) + \frac{y_1^2}{h_1}\right)\right) +...+ \frac {\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(h_n) + \frac{y_n^2}{h_n}\right)\right) = 0$$

This does *not* mean that each derivative separately is set equal to zero

**2)** The (outer product of the) Gradient, and the Hessian used in the Asymptotic Variance are those of the likelihood *for the typical observation $t$* namely,

$$B(\theta_0) = \frac {\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(h_t) + \frac{y_t^2}{h_t}\right)\right) \cdot \frac {\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(h_t) + \frac{y_t^2}{h_t}\right)\right)^T$$

$$A(\theta_0) = \frac {\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(h_t) + \frac{y_t^2}{h_t}\right)\right)$$

Their sample estimates are sample means of the above evaluated at $\hat \theta$, so, for the outer product of the Gradient,

$$B(\hat \theta) = \frac 1n \sum_{t=1}^n\left[\frac {\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(h_t) + \frac{y_t^2}{h_t}\right)\right)\cdot \frac {\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(h_t) + \frac{y_t^2}{h_t}\right)\right)^T\right]$$

which doesn't equal zero.